# file types grouped, how to ungroup

Tags: windows-7, file-extension, komodoedit

in windows 7, after installed Komodo Edit, i tried to change filetype icon using FileTypesMan from NirSoft, but as weird as it is, as soon as I change desription for .js it changes to the same too for .php and vice-versa the other way too. My guess is, maybe Komodo added it to some file types group, but dunno how to diferentiate them? My primary goal is to have a custom php icon for php and js files (each one different)

any experience anyone, or suggestions? 
Newer heard before of such binding between different file extensions

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Komodo uses your system file icons so it does not have direct control over what language icons you see. If you'd want to change those icons you would have to do it at the system level.

Note that we will most likely be using our own language icons in one of our next releases, which should solve issues like the one you are having.

Note that if you're feeling really adventurous you could develop an addon or customize the source directly (available at https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit). Feel free to join us on IRC if you have any questions - #komodo on irc.mozilla.org.

Source: Komodo Dev.